# Mesh explodes before impact

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigid-body-simulation

This is driving me nuts. I have done cell fracture. (I did merge by distance to clean up). I have them all set to "deactivation" and "start Deactivated" checked.

On the sphere coming to hit it's set to animated.

But the mesh just blows up the moment the simulation starts on the first frame. I've removed rigid body and re-applied a few times. I've restarted blender. nothing. Help!!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i would suggest to provide blend file so we can check it out.

Comment: Have you applied the scale of your objects?